# Permanent magnet DC motor earth wire

Tags: arduino, motor, dc, pwm, earth

I have just inherited a piece of equipment that is powered by a 12V DC permanent magnet motor. My hope is to drive it using an Arduino PWM and a H-Bridge to manage the current requirements (7.3A continuous load, peaks at around 10A on start up). That is all fine and good and working, my only concern is that there are three wires coming from the motor, a red and black which I've taken as the DC input. Plus another wire, green and yellow striped like a mains earth.

My question is, is this just an earthing cable for the metal case? and where should this be attached I'm presuming it shouldn't go to the DC ground.

Comment: Can you locate a data sheet for the motor? When you say it is "powered by a 12V DC permanent magnet motor", what specifically does that mean?

Comment: I've looked at a few places the actual data sheet doesn't mention it. But the catalogue from the manufacturer references an "earth tag point" I presume it's this. It was previously attached to mains ground in the power supply.

Comment: I could not think of any other place than earth to connect a protective earth wire...

Comment: @Andyaka [link](http://www.parvalux.com/dload/ebrochures/pm-catalogue-2009/files/assets/downloads/page0020.pdf). It's a piece of experimental equipment that we use in the lab and it is effectively a motorised arm with a DC motor and lead screw. It's very simple at the moment and will either fully extend or withdraw on a timer. I have modified the code to allow a much more complex range of motion but am just confused about the earth connection on a DC motor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an earth wire then it's probably there because the motor windings do not offer full reinforced insulation. This might be because the motor was (or is) intended to be used with a 12V power supply that isn't necessarily isolated from AC mains voltages and, the earth wire will protect users from receiving electric shocks should they touch the motor. In effect if a fault develops potential live voltages will cause an earth current and either a fuse or breaker will trip rendering the installation safe.

It could also be that the earth wire is for EMC reasons but without a clear data sheet or comment from the supplier, play safe; use a meter to determine that the power wires are insulated from the "earth" wire - if there appears to be some form of galvanic connection then you really have to get information back from the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I've checked the leads and there's no connection between the power leads and the earth. I presume I should leave it connected to mains ground in case of a fault?

Comment: If you are powering it from a DC supply that is "safe" then no, you don't need to but, if the wire is there for EMC reasons then maybe so.

Comment: The star of the windings should be isolated from case. If this was a higher voltage motor this would be for safety but as this is a low-voltage it will be for EMC.  There will be some capacitance from the star to case & equally a potential capacitance path via the bearings (pwm is nasty for bearings...). Tying it to EARTH might not be the best solution, especially if the H-bridge (note h-bridge) is powered from a battery with no path to EARTH/Neutral.   Think about the current flow and where it wants to get back to

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the third wire is a tacho output, uncommon but not unheard of. Quick way to check, see if you can measure the resistance between the wire and the case, less than a few ohms and it's an earth, a few to a few tens of kohms (may be polarity dependent) and it's some kind of semiconductor device output (tacho?) if it's in the Meg range or is too high to measure, it could be an EMC shield (I've got a tiny 3ph motor like this)